# Is Dictionary Ordering on $\mathbb{R}^2$ Connected?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, connectedness

I'm working on the following question:

> Is every interval in the Dictionary Ordering on $\mathbb{R}^2$ equipped with the order topology connected?

My answer is no: Let $[a,b]$ be an interval where $a = (1,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $b=(3,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Then sets $$A = \{1\} \times \mathbb{R}_+ \, \bigcup \, (1,2] \times  \mathbb{R} \\ B = \{3\} \times \mathbb{R}_- \, \bigcup \, (2,3) \times  \mathbb{R}$$ form a separation of $[a,b]$ (both sets are open in the this topology).

However, I'm worried, because dictionary Ordering on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a linear continuum - and all such sets with the order topology are connected.

What's the issue here?

Comment: o wait, I don't think the dictionary Ordering on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a linear continuum. there are sets that don't have a least upper bound...i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote yourself in the comments where is that the problem lies: $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the dictionary order is not a linear continuuum. For instance $\left\{(0,x)\,\middle|\,x\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$ has an upper bound ($(1,0)$, for instance), but it has no supremum.

Comment: horray! okay, i thought so.

Comment: i was second guessing because the ordered square is a linear continuum (so says Munkres)

Comment: But the ordered square is not a subspace of the ordered plane. @yoshi

Comment: The connected components of the ordered plane are all stalks $\{x\} \times \mathbb{R}$. @yoshi

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Ah! thanks for pointing this out, this is where I went astray, in my head, I created the ordered box with a set from the usual top on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: @yoshi The ordered square has its own topology, which it neither inherits from the usual (metric/product) topology on the plane, nor from the ordered plane (which is just a bunch of vertical lines next to each other). It even contains a homeomorphic copy of the lower limit topology...